# Django - how to redirect from to another basic on first forms choices

Tags: django, forms, redirect

I would like to write simple app in which i'd like to have workflow :
1) user answers form "A"
2) basic on answer of qustion A.a redirect to form "B" or to form "C"
3) save whole instance

All three forms will use the same model (leaving unused fiels as blank).
What is the best way - to save instance partialy and redirect to next forms using for example primary key parameter or push "partialy" answered form to the next form and then save all at once.

How should i redirect ? set success_url of A to a view which, based on POST A.a redirects me the another form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have only one instance?
I would try to refactor it using 3 instances.

If this is not possible, I would store the partial entity in the user session and save at the last step (B or C).

As for the redirect, if you are using the Class Based Views, take a look at `form_valid` method: it receives the (already validated) form and you just need to save it and redirect.

[This is](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) an awesome reference to Class Based Views.